# Why does tf.get_variable('test') returns a variable with name test_1?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I created a tensorflow variable with `tf.Variable`.  I wonder why if I call `tf.get_variable` with the same name no exception is raised and a new variable is created with an incremented name ?

```
import tensorflow as tf

class QuestionTest(tf.test.TestCase):

    def test_version(self):
        self.assertEqual(tf.__version__, '1.10.1')

    def test_variable(self):
        a = tf.Variable(0., trainable=False, name='test')
        self.assertEqual(a.name, "test:0")

        b = tf.get_variable('test', shape=(), trainable=False)
        self.assertEqual(b.name, "test_1:0")

        self.assertNotEqual(a, b, msg='`a` is not `b`')

        with self.assertRaises(ValueError) as ecm:
            tf.get_variable('test', shape=(), trainable=False)
        exception = ecm.exception
        self.assertStartsWith(str(exception), "Variable test already exists, disallowed.")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `tf.Variable` is a low level method which stores created variable in GLOBALS (or LOCALS) collection while `tf.get_variable` keeps account of the variable it has created by storing them in a variable store.

When you first call `tf.Variable`, the variable created is not added to the variable store letting think that no variable with name `"test"` has been created.

So, when you later call `tf.get_variable("test")` it will look at the variable store, see that no variable with name `"test"` is in it.
It will thus call `tf.Variable`, which will create a variable with an incremented name `"test_1"` stored in the variable store under the key `"test"`.

```
import tensorflow as tf

class AnswerTest(tf.test.TestCase):

    def test_version(self):
        self.assertEqual(tf.__version__, '1.10.1')    

    def test_variable_answer(self):
        """Using the default variable scope"""
        # Let first check the __variable_store and the GLOBALS collections.
        self.assertListEqual(tf.get_collection(("__variable_store",)), [], 
                             "No variable store.")
        self.assertListEqual(tf.global_variables(), [],
                             "No global variables")

        a = tf.Variable(0., trainable=False, name='test')
        self.assertEqual(a.name, "test:0")
        self.assertListEqual(tf.get_collection(("__variable_store",)), [],
                             "No variable store.")
        self.assertListEqual(tf.global_variables(), [a],
                             "but `a` is in global variables.")

        b = tf.get_variable('test', shape=(), trainable=False)
        self.assertNotEqual(a, b, msg='`a` is not `b`')
        self.assertEqual(b.name, "test_1:0", msg="`b`'s name is not 'test'.")
        self.assertTrue(len(tf.get_collection(("__variable_store",))) > 0,
                        "There is now a variable store.")
        var_store = tf.get_collection(("__variable_store",))[0]
        self.assertDictEqual(var_store._vars, {"test": b},
                             "and variable `b` is in it.")
        self.assertListEqual(tf.global_variables(), [a, b],
                             "while `a` and `b` are in global variables.")

        with self.assertRaises(ValueError) as exception_context_manager:
            tf.get_variable('test', shape=(), trainable=False)
        exception = exception_context_manager.exception
        self.assertStartsWith(str(exception),
                              "Variable test already exists, disallowed.")
```

The same is true when using an explicit variable scope.

```
    def test_variable_answer_with_variable_scope(self):
        """Using now a variable scope"""
        self.assertListEqual(tf.get_collection(("__variable_store",)), [], 
                             "No variable store.")

        with tf.variable_scope("my_scope") as scope:
            self.assertTrue(len(tf.get_collection(("__variable_store",))) > 0, 
                            "There is now a variable store.")
            var_store = tf.get_collection(("__variable_store",))[0]
            self.assertDictEqual(var_store._vars, {},
                                 "but with variable in it.")

            a = tf.Variable(0., trainable=False, name='test')
            self.assertEqual(a.name, "my_scope/test:0")
            var_store = tf.get_collection(("__variable_store",))[0]
            self.assertDictEqual(var_store._vars, {},
                                 "Still no variable in the store.")


            b = tf.get_variable('test', shape=(), trainable=False)
            self.assertEqual(b.name, "my_scope/test_1:0")
            var_store = tf.get_collection(("__variable_store",))[0]
            self.assertDictEqual(
                var_store._vars, {"my_scope/test": b},
                "`b` is in the store, but notice the difference between its name and its key in the store.")

            with self.assertRaises(ValueError) as exception_context_manager:
                tf.get_variable('test', shape=(), trainable=False)
            exception = exception_context_manager.exception
            self.assertStartsWith(str(exception),
                                  "Variable my_scope/test already exists, disallowed.")
```